# valums Ajax file uploader+406 not acceptable Error In Firbug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using [Valums Ajax Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) on my website. Everything is working fine on my local computer but when i try the same uploader on my website main server then Firbug shows this error:

**POST http://www.myexampledomain.com/upload.php?qqfile=201004151821387.1.flv 406 Not Acceptable 8.37s

        fileuploader.js (line 1204)**

**Response Body**

```
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /upload.php could not be found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
```

All Request & Response header are [here](http://pastebin.com/jbW1x93z) and in `fileuploader.js` file code near to line no 1204 is:

```
 params = params || {};
 params['qqfile'] = name;
 var queryString = qq.obj2url(params, this._options.action);

 xhr.open("POST", queryString, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(name));
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
 xhr.send(file); //line 1204
```

I have already searched on Google and this website but nothing useful is found so please tell me how can i solve this problem?

My other question regarding this problem - [406 error on firebug only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958448/406-error-on-firebug-only)

Comment: upload.php is also in proper folder,i checked it by accessing it direcly

Comment: Does a simple `.txt` file upload without error? Or are all uploads failing with a 406?

Comment: no .txt also result the same 406 error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in mod_security.

Probably, you have the rule to block all file upload requests if their content encoding is different from form (not multipart/form-data or form-urlencoded).

First - you can comment that line in your apache config file.

Second (and more convinient regarding valums uploader) - add encoding: 'multipart' options to your fileuploader - that will add multipart/form-data for Content-Encoding so apache will allow that request.

Comment: how to add multipart/form-data to the ajax request?

Comment: for valums uploader add parameter
encoding: 'multipart',

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, and i resolved it by disabling mod_security in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 

   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

Please use above at your own risk, as disabling mod_security can anticipate some security hole server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`mod_security`](http://www.modsecurity.org/) is getting in the way. It seem that one (only?) way to solve this is to disable POST scanning by adding to your [`.htaccess`](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/htaccess.html) the following:

```
<ifmodule mod_security.c>
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</ifmodule>
```

I would try to add an `.htaccess` to the root directory of your application and hope it works as hosting provider may not allow user specific `.htaccess` files.

Relevant article - http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2008/05/01/http-406-errors-galore.html

Comment: You might not be able to [override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) the hosting provider settings. Have you asked them about this? http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php also useful summary of `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help solve your problem, but I recently came across this same issue with POST'ing using JQuery $.ajax. I also had a similar problem using JQuery Qaptcha which also uses a bit of ajax and a POST.

On both occasion I was able to change the POST to a GET (including in the php files that were being called) and it would then work on my host's live server.

I have yet to fully understand the good or the bad of doing this as I am pretty inexperienced in this area, so if someone has any thoughts as to whether this is a bad thing to do, then input would be appreciated.

Example:

```
    if($cust_acceptance == 'yes') {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", //Swapped out a POST for a GET.
        url: "/scripts/php/update_shortlist.php",
        data: "action=add&shortlist_id="+shortlist_id+"&rb_ref="+rb_ref,
        success: function(msg){
            //alert ("success: "+rb_ref);
```

I think the other people are correct that it is permission issues with mod_security, but you are unlikely to be able to convince your hosting company to change these settings for you - if you are using a shared service. Obviously if you are on a VPS or dedicated server you can make the changes needed yourself.

Hope that helps.